# Encrypt Data Prior to Upload

Tags: encryption, sftp

I'm looking to store some data online but I want to encrypt the files first. Since I understand that sFTP will only encrypt the transmission of the data, I'm wondering what program others use to encrypt their files prior to sFTPing them to a backup server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Privacy Guard](http://www.gnupg.org/) is a good choice, if the keys are also secured.

Comment: encrypting with `gpg` is as easy as `gpg --recipient email@example.com file-to-encrypt` creating your public/private keypair is also quite simple, and more than likely outlined on the `gpg` homepage Ignacio has linked you to.

Answer (score 2):

Also [Bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) is a free Blowfish implementation. 448-bit encryption, cross-platform compatible, very easy to compile from scratch, or most distro have a package, and there's a Win32 download on the website.

It's password based, so no key files to hang on to. [Just don't pick a really bad password](http://wolfram.org/writing/howto/password.html).

Answer (score 2):

Although PGP is a commercial product (GPG is an opensource implementation of PGP), you might find that one of the free, older versions works.

Chris beat me to something I was going to suggest: if you use PGP or GPG, and you can use conventional encryption where you pick a password or passphrase to encrypt the files with instead of setting up public/private keys.